# Inline SVG not showing in pug and webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, pug-loader

I'm using Webpack4 with pug as my template engine. My config is all set up and everything works ok.

I want to add the odd inline SVG icon in my pug templates and am using this using [HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-svg-plugin) which has worked for my first SVG but not my second.

**My 'common' config file (I have dev and prod versions too as per Webpack docs):**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-svg-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.pug',
      title: 'Output Management',
      minify: {
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true // removes type="text/javascript" from injected <script> tags
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin({
      runPreEmit: true,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug-loader',
        query: {
          pretty: true // false is default. Set to true to not minify resulting html
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

### THIS WORKS

**header.pug template**

```
img(inline src="src/images/icons/close-icon.svg")
```

**close-icon.svg contents:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
    <path d="m1.3761 1.3683 12.288 12.288m-12.328-0.024469 12.288-12.288" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3272"></path>
</svg>
```

This shows fine.
However another SVG won't show using the same method:

### SVG CODE COMPILES INTO INDEX.HTML FILE BUT ICON DOESN"T SHOW AND BITS ARE STRIPPED OUT

**search.pug template**

```
img(inline src="src/images/icons/search-icon.svg")
```

**search-icon.svg contents:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg class="search__icon" role="img" aria-labelledby="header-search-ico" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title id="header-search-ico">Search</title>
<path d="m13.052 6.4998c-5.2483 8.909e-4 -9.5022 4.2558-9.502 9.5041 8.962e-4 5.2476 4.2545 9.5012 9.502 9.502 5.2483 2.89e-4 9.5033-4.2536 9.5041-9.502 2.9e-4 -5.2491-4.255-9.5043-9.5041-9.5041zm7.0353 16.224 6.5139 6.6193s0.4042 0.41477-6.5139-6.6193z" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```

**Resulting html**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-labelledby="header-search-ico" class="search__icon" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
<path fill="none" d="M13.052 6.5a9.504 9.504 0 1 0 .003 19.007A9.504 9.504 0 0 0 13.052 6.5zm7.035 16.224l6.514 6.62s.404.414-6.514-6.62z"></path></svg>
```

So the `<title>` tag and below attributes are getting stripped out plus the path looks screwed up. Does anybody have any experience using inline SVGs in pug templates using webpack?

- role
- width
- height
- stroke-linecap

Comment: Your problems have nothing to do with pug or webpack, and the path is OK too, it just converts relative to absolute coordinate data. What is missing is a `stroke` attribute (or a corresponding CSS property) in search-icon.svg. As a result, `fill` and `stroke` both compute to `"none"`, and the icon remains invisible.

Comment: BTW, the tags and attributes stripped out are governed by the SVGO configuration [mentioned here](https://github.com/thegc/html-webpack-inline-svg-plugin#config). To improve a11y, I would set `removeTitle: false`, everything else is sensible enough.

Comment: Thanks @ccprog I couldn't see the wood for the trees on that one! Add this as the answer and I'll tick it. :-)